# python mqtt subscribe to mutliple message

Tags: python, mqtt, publish-subscribe

I do publish multiple messages:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import paho.mqtt.publish as publish

topic1 = "testtopic/topic1"
topic2 = "testtopic/topic2"

val1 = b'54.8'
val2 = b'598.45'
val3 = b'4813.9'

msgs = [(topic1, val1),
        (topic1, val2),
        (topic2, val3)]

publish.multiple(msgs, hostname="localhost")
```

When subscribing to it

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
import json

broker_url = "localhost"
broker_port = 1883

def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
    print("Connected With Result Code: {}".format(rc))
def on_disconnect(client, userdata, rc):
    print("Client Got Disconnected")
def on_message(client, userdata, message):
    msg = json.loads(message.payload.decode())
    print("Message Recieved: " + str(msg))
    
client = mqtt.Client()
client.connect(broker_url, broker_port)

client.on_connect = on_connect
client.on_message = on_message
client.on_disconnect = on_disconnect

topic = "testtopic/#"

client.subscribe(topic, qos=0)

client.loop_forever()
```

I get this

```
Connected With Result Code: 0
Message Recieved: 54.8
Message Recieved: 598.45
Message Recieved: 4813.9
```

How can I assign the three values to single varables (e.g. value1 = 54.8, value2 = 598.45, value3 = 598.45) to be able to work with them like doing some calculations or saving it to file.

Comment: Maybe each time you receive a message, append it to a list?

Comment: you can pusblish values in JSON like {"value1": 54.8, "value2": 598.45, "value3": 598.45}

Answer (score 0):

You can use JSON format like this below..

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import paho.mqtt.publish as publish

topic1 = "testtopic/topic1"
topic2 = "testtopic/topic2"

val1 = b'54.8'
val2 = b'598.45'
val3 = b'4813.9'

payload1=json.dumps({"value1":val1, "value2":val2})
payload2=json.dumps({"value3":val3)

msgs = [(topic1, payload1),
        (topic2, payload2)]

publish.multiple(msgs, hostname="localhost")
```

and for subscriber in on_message function...

```
def on_message(client, userdata, message):
    msg = json.loads(message.payload.decode())
    res=json.loads(str(msg))
    if message.topic == topic1:
           print(str(res["value1"])+" & "+str(res["value2"]))
    else:
           print(str(res["value2"]))
```